# How to disable field column in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, field

How to disable field column in jqgrid?
this is my code :

```
jQuery("#penanggungJawab").jqGrid({
    mtype: "GET",
    datatype:"json",
    height: 50,
    width:900,
    colNames:['ID Card','Type Id Card','NO Id Card', 'Expired Date'],
    colModel:[ {
        name:'idCardIdPnggungJwb',
        index:'idCardIdPnggungJwb',
        width:310,
        editable:true,
        hidden:false,
        ***disabled:true***
    }, {
        name:'typeIdCardPnggungJwb',
        index:'typeIdCardPnggungJwb',
        width:310,
        editable:true,
        edittype:"select",
        editoptions:{value:"KTP:KTP;IDC:ID Card Company"},
        jsonmap:'typeIdCard'
    }, {
        name:'nomorIdCardPnggungJwb',
        index:'nomorIdCardPnggungJwb',
        width:310,
        editable:true
    },{
        name:'expiredDatePnggungJwb',
        index:'expiredDatePnggungJwb',
        width:310,
        editable:true,
        editoptions:{size:12, dataInit:function(el) {
            $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:"yy/mm/dd",changeMonth: true,changeYear: true});
        },
    }}],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#Keuangan',
    sortname: 'typeIdCardPenanggungJawabKeuangan',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"Grid No Kartu Identitas",
    editurl: "noabjad.json"
}); jQuery("#penanggungJawab").jqGrid('navGrid','#Keuangan',{
    del:false,
    search:false,
    edit:false
},{
    reloadAfterSubmit:false
},{
    reloadAfterSubmit:false
});
```

Can I disable one of the columns, that can not be edited?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you want. You use `editable:false` so the column will be not edited. Which kind of "disabling" you want have?

Comment: im sorry, i mean when editing field not can be click.Can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correct you need use

```
editoptions: {disabled: true}
```

option for the `'idCardIdPnggungJwb'` column. The results you will see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/soccerenz.htm).