# Disable column in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have this jqGrid:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: '/modulos/carga/cargaServiciosTarifa.ashx',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['Tipo_Servicio', 'Cantidad','Unidad'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'Tipo_Servicio', index: 'TSI_TS_Id', width: 100, align: 'center',
            edittype: 'select', editable: true, sortable: true,
            editrules: { edithidden: false, required: true }, editoptions: {
                size: 1,
                dataUrl: '/modulos/carga/cargaServiciosTarifa.ashx?oper=getServicios'
            }},
        { name: 'Cantidad', index: 'TSI_Cantidad', width: 100, align: 'center',
            editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                value: "1:1;2:2;3:3;4:4;5:5;6:6;7:7;8:8;9:9;10:10;11:11;12:12" },
            editrules: { edithidden: true }, sortable: true },
        { name: 'Unidad', index: 'TSI_Unidad', width: 100, align: 'center',
            editable: true, edittype: 'select',
            editoptions: { value: "Dia:Dia;Hora:Hora" }, sortable: true }
    ],
    autoencode: true,
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum: 20,
    sortname: 'TSI_TS_Id',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    sortable: true,
    autowidth: false,
    width: 733,
    height: -1,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Listado Servicios asociados a Tarifa',
    postData: {tarId: tarId.val()},
    editurl: '/modulos/carga/cargaServiciosTarifa.ashx'
});
```

With three select options, and I want to know how can I disable the 'Cantidad'(second column) select if I select the option 'Dia' of the third (last) select called 'Unidad', but can use if I select 'Hora' option! Is there a possible way to do this when I create or edit(no inline editing)?

Have any property like a html disabled to can add to the `colModel` definition?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7050386/1538708

Comment: Yes, I know this option, but i want to put/quit this option depending of the value of another select, is not the same! Thanks!

Comment: @bombai: In case of editing it's very important to specify **exactly** which editing mode (form editing, cell editing or inline editing) and how you use it. If you use `navGrid`, `inlineNav`, `formatter: "actions"` and so on it's important to specify which one. In all of the cases it's possible to solve your problem, but the solution way *is different* depend on the way how you implemented editing of rows or cells.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for your response, I use navgrid, i forgot to specify. Can you tell me how can I fix it? Thanks a lot!